# How to set NDK Build path in Windows for Android studio

Tags: android-studio, openframeworks

According to the  openFrameWorks instructions, I import an example project, and the first error is this:

> gradle version 2.2 is required. current version is 2.10

After changing it to "gradle version 2.2", I get this error:

> NDK directory is invalid. Check NDK_ROOT path in paths.make

If I change `NDK_ROOT` to `path_to/android-ndk-r10e` following Google, it doesn't help either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is `path_to/` really `path_to/` ? or it's the absolute path to your NDK ?

Comment: problem has been solve,God wants us to meet a few wrong people woke up a language